# Scraping coordinate data and additional information for shot locations

Tags: r, rvest

I'm learning about R, by looking at basketball statistics, and I want to pull out information that is presented in a shot chart.

I'm looking at the following shot chart for D'Angelo Russell, at:

```
https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/russeda01/shooting/2019
```

I'm scraping data using tools within the `library(rvest)` package, in the following way:

```
> dlo_html <- read_html("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/russeda01/shooting/2019")
> dlo_nodes1 <- html_nodes(dlo_html, "table")
> dlo_makes <- html_table(dlo_nodes1)
```

... so now when I run `head(dlo_makes)` I get a data.frame of 74 rows and 11 columns to sort through from the table from left side of the webpage. That's a nice start.

However, what I **really** want is the information contained in the shot chart graphic on the right side of the page. I can see it in the source code of the html. If you search for `shot-area` in the source, right below it are about 1500 rows of data that look like this:

```
<div style="top:57px;left:237px;" tip="Oct 17, 2018, BRK at DET<br>1st Qtr, 10:38 remaining<br>Missed 2-pointer from 2 ft<br>BRK leads 2-0" class="tooltip miss">&#215;</div>
<div style="top:154px;left:341px;" tip="Oct 17, 2018, BRK at DET<br>1st Qtr, 10:30 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 14 ft<br>BRK now leads 4-0" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>
etc.
```

Am I passing incorrect information into the `html_nodes()` command? Or should I be using a different command than `html_table` to look at the nodes? Or is there something else that I'm missing here?

Comment: It may be because the data in the shot chart are loaded dynamically - see this old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473847/rvest-not-recognizing-css-selector)

Comment: Be aware that this use may not be allowed by this site's terms of service: https://www.sports-reference.com/data_use.html

Comment: @kstew - thanks for the link, that gives me some to think on.

Comment: @Brian - Thanks for alerting me to that. But there's a line in the link: "I would point out that learning how to accumulate data is often a more valuable skill than actually analyzing the data, so we encourage you as a student or professional to learn how." I will not hammer their website with requests, if I can avoid it, and learn to get data from other sources as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want is written as a comment not loaded dynamically.

I used the view source to get the div that contains the data and it called

**all_shot-chart**

so here's the code for getting what you want

```
dlo_html <- read_html("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/r/russeda01/shooting/2019")

Commented_Section <- dlo_html%>%html_nodes("[id = 'all_shot-chart']")%>%html_nodes(xpath = 'comment()')%>%
        html_text() %>% read_html() %>%html_node('table')

Missed_Plays <- Commented_Section %>% html_nodes("[class='tooltip miss']")
Maked_Plays <- Commented_Section %>% html_nodes("[class='tooltip make']")
```

i could find in this question how to get the commented sections.

[How to read a commented out HTML table using readHTMLTable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420282/how-to-read-a-commented-out-html-table-using-readhtmltable-in-r)

Comment: That solution got me a lot closer to where I wanted to be at. Thanks, @Omar Abd El-Naser.